# Store such characters in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm storing encrypted passwords in the database, It worked perfect so far on MachineA. Now that I moved to MachineB it seems like the results gets corrupted in the table.

For example:  `ù9qÆæ\2 Ý-³Å¼]ó` will change to `?9q??\2 ?-³?¼]?` in the table.

That's the query I use:

```
ALTER PROC [Employees].[pRegister](@UserName NVARCHAR(50),@Password VARCHAR(150))

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @Id = NEWID()

SET @password = HashBytes('MD5', @password + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@Id))

SELECT @Password

INSERT INTO Employees.Registry (Id,[Name],[Password]) VALUES (@Id, @UserName,@Password) 

END
```

- Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
- ProductVersion: 10.50.1600.1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing 2 datatypes:

- password need to be nvarchar to support non-Western European characters
- literals need N prefix

Demo:

```
DECLARE @pwdgood nvarchar(150), @pwdbad varchar(150)
SET @pwdgood = N'ù9qÆæ\2 Ý-³Å¼]ó'
SET @pwdbad = N'?9q??\2 ?-³?¼]?'
SELECT @pwdgood, @pwdbad
```

- HashBytes gives varbinary(8000) so you need *this* in the table

Note: I'd also consider salting the stored password with something *other* than ID column for that row

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store such characters, you need to:

- use `NVARCHAR` as the datatype for your columns and parameters (`@Password` **isn't** `NVARCHAR` and the `CAST` you're using to assign the password in the database table isn't using `NVARCHAR` either, in your sample ...)
- use the `N'....'` syntax for indicating Unicode string literals

With those two in place, you should absolutely be able to store and retrieve any valid Unicode character